# Only add item as needed in PHP array

Tags: php, loops

I have bits of code I want to throw in to my site, and provisioned a space right after `<body>` using 'flairs' (divs) that sit outside the design. Here's the code:

```
//Add Flair Containers as needed
if($flairs>0){
  echo "<!--Flair Graphics (if needed)-->\n";
    while($fQty = --$flairs+1){ //-- subracts 1, +1 accounts for 1 being 0
       $flair = array($flair1, $flair2, $flair3);
        foreach($flair as $flairCode){
          echo "<div id=\"flair-".$fQty++."\">".$flairCode."</div>\n";
        };
    };
};
```

It prints correctly, where content = $flair1, $flair2, and so on.

```
<div id="flair-1">Content1</div>
<div id="flair-2">Content2</div>
<div id="flair-3">Content3</div>
```

But if $flair2/$flair3 is empty, it still prints a div. How can I fix this?

Comment: well what `$fQty = --$flairs+1`  does isnt it make $flairs always same for example if $flairs is 5 -- makes it 4 and +1 five ?

Comment: And to your question, even if `$flair2`/`$flair3` is empty, `$flair` is still an array with elements (at least with `$flair1`, not to mention `null` still makes up an element), so `foreach` still runs.

Comment: @passerby Yes, I knew it would I just couldn't figure out a way to check if it exists. @ nullpointer the +1 simply makes the value print correctly. There's probably a better way, but that worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your `foreach` loop you can check if the value is [`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) and [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) (i.e. skip) to the next value if it is.

Like so:

```
if($flairs>0){
  echo "<!--Flair Graphics (if needed)-->\n";
    while($fQty = --$flairs+1){ //-- subracts 1, +1 accounts for 1 being 0
       $flair = array($flair1, $flair2, $flair3);
        foreach($flair as $flairCode){
          if (empty($flairCode)) continue;
          echo "<div id=\"flair-".$fQty++."\">".$flairCode."</div>\n";
        };
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you could simply prepend `if($flairCode)` to your echo statement. That would make your inner loop:

```
foreach($flair as $flairCode){
    if($flairCode) echo "<div id=\"flair-".$fQty++."\">".$flairCode."</div>\n";
};
```

Some points to note:

- Since the `$flair` array will always be the same, construct it outside of the loop (this will let you evaluate the condition only once too.
- Using `$fQty++` is not enough to guarantee unique ID's, especially since every time it hits the `while` the value is reset. I suggest `$fQty` should not be part of the `while` condition and simply stay as an independent tally.
- Stop using double-quotes. They're slow.

Comment: You'll need the double quotes if you want to include line breaks (\n). Also, the performance hit for double vs single quotes is negligible if it exists at all. See [Disproving the Single Quotes Performance Myth](http://nikic.github.com/2012/01/09/Disproving-the-Single-Quotes-Performance-Myth.html).

Comment: Cool. I use single quote whenever possible, but I want my final code to look good. I was a designer before I was a programmer, so it matters to me.

Comment: Line breaks can be done with `PHP_EOL` (which gives the platform specific line ending so I would argue that it is better anyway). As to single vs. double those numbers are new to me. The last time I ran a benchmark had single quotes running about 1-2% faster consistently. I'll see if I can't re-run his application both from a server and from the command line and see what pops up.

Comment: I will say that since he is concatenating manually anyway, and since he is escaping double-quotes to do that, I think his code would still be better formatted if he were to use single-quotes.